# A converted vc++ 2003 project asks for msvcpd71d.dll when compiled on vc++2008

Tags: visual-c++

After running the conversion wizard for a VC++ 2003 project - which ends with no errors - I get VC++ 2008 to sucessfully compile the project. Then, when launching the exe, a message pops up saying that the program cannot start because MSVCP71D.dll is missing. Any ideas on why a project compiled on vc++ 2008 would ask for MSVCP71D.dll ?

TIA

Update: I am trying to compile the ARToolkit using VC2008.
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/artoolkit/files/artoolkit/2.72.1/ARToolKit-2.72.1-bin-win32.zip/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What binary files came with the project?  You seem to be linking against a static library or DLL that was built with VS7.1 -- hopefully you can rebuild that file in VC9 there.

Also, for what it's worth, note that the D at the end of "MSVCP71D.dll" indicates that it's looking for a *debug* build of that DLL.

---

The ARToolkit has several libraries in the `lib` folder, some of which with that same "d" suffix indicating a debug build -- those libraries were most likely built in VS2003 given your results.  I'm not sure if you can rebuild in VS2008 from the `lib/SRC` directory, but that might be a start.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to compile the ARToolkit using VC2008

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to build it as "release" so that the application does not look for that debug library at run-time.

Comment: That's not a fair answer. Debug mode should still remain a viable option to answer this question.